# Why, although my update operation does the job correctly, it returns an empty value at the end

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-getx

I am making a todo app
My update verb is not working for me here
In this action, it first takes the values ​​from the text box so that it can register a task, but as you can see, it returns a null value in the terminal and does not register anything.

The program works in such a way that when you give it a task, it should record data as a task, but it does not record anything.
please help

this code in controller

```
updateTask(Task task, String title) {
    var todos = task.todos ?? [];
    if (containTodo(todos, title)) {
      return false;
    }
    var todo = {'title': title, 'done': false};
    todos.add(todo);
    var newTask = task.copyWith(todos: todos);
    int oldIdx = tasks.indexOf(task);
    tasks[oldIdx] = newTask;
    tasks.refresh();
    print(task.todos);
    return true;
  }

  bool containTodo(List todos, String title) {
    return todos.any((element) => element['title'] == title);
  }
```

this code in view

```
TextButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      overlayColor:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if(homeCtrl.formKey.currentState!.validate()){
                        if(homeCtrl.task.value== null){
                          EasyLoading.showError('Please select task type');
                        }
                        else{
                          var success = homeCtrl.updateTask(
                            homeCtrl.task.value!,
                            homeCtrl.editCtrl.text,
                          );
                          if(success){
                            EasyLoading.showSuccess('Todo item add success');
                            Get.back();
                            homeCtrl.changeTask(null);
                          }
                          else{
                            EasyLoading.showError('Todo item already exist');
                          }
                          homeCtrl.editCtrl.clear();
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Done",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0.sp),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0.wp),
              child: Text(
                'New Task',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0.wp),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: homeCtrl.editCtrl,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[400]!),
                  ),
                ),
                autofocus: true,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your todo item';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ),
```

I expect a number to be added to my task count when I hit the done button

in terminal this messages

```
I/flutter ( 5771): null
[GETX] CLOSE TO ROUTE /AddDialog
I/TextInputPlugin( 5771): Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5771): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5771): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5771): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be from different things, for one thing `todos.add(todo);`,

```
    var todos = task.todos ?? [];
    ...
    todos.add(todo);
    ...
    tasks[oldIdx] = newTask;
    tasks.refresh();
    print(task.todos);
```

are you sure the `task.todos` get updated? cause it may be copied by value which means the update for `todos` variable won't update `task.todos`....

Moreover, what if `task.todos` was null, so `todos` will take the value `[]` and for sure `task.todos` won't be updated .... so try now to print `todos` after or before `print(task.todos);` and if not updated try to update `task.todos` directly.

Also you should make sure `tasks[oldIdx]` is getting updated.
And one more advice make sure to add try,catch to handle any errors may occur for example for a reason or another `oldIdx` can be -1 or out of range, and that will throw an error.

An advance advice, for todo model, it is better to create a model for it instead of using maps, this will make your coding much easier if you don't know that already. Check [this article on Medium](https://tomicriedel.medium.com/flutter-freezed-the-complete-crashcourse-c942e9aa2428) where in general`freezed` and `json_serializable` used to build the models in FLutter